# Regex to get one character not followed with digit

Tags: c#, regex

How can I get first character if not have int inside:

I need to look all the place have `'['` without integer after.

For example:

```
[abc] pass
[cxvjk234] pass
[123] fail
```

Right now, I have this:

```
((([[])([^0-9])))
```

It gets the first 2 characters while I need only one.

Comment: `([[])`? Why not just `\[`?

Comment: Use `@"(?<=\[)\D"`

Comment: Could you please check our answers and see if they are working for you? Your description is a bit unclear.

Answer (score 2):

**In general**, to match some pattern not followed with a digit, you need to add a `(?!\d)` / `(?![0-9])` [negative lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to the expression:

```
\[(?!\d)
\[(?![0-9])
  ^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5C%5B%28%3F!%5Cd%29&i=%5Babc%5D%20pass%0D%0A%5Bcxvjk234%5D%20pass%0D%0A%5B123%5D%20fail). This matches any `[` symbol that is not immediately followed with a digit.

---

Your current regex pattern is overloaded with capturing groups, and if we remove those redundant ones, it looks like `(\[)([^0-9])` - it matches a `[` and then a char other than an ASCII digit.

You may use

```
(?<=\[)\D
```

or (if you want to only match the ASCII digits with the pattern only)

```
(?<=\[)[^0-9]
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c%3d%5c%5b)%5b%5e0-9%5d&i=%5babc%5d+pass%0d%0a%5bcxvjk234%5d+pass%0d%0a%5b123%5d+fail&o=e)

*Details*:

- `(?<=\[)` - a positive lookbehind requiring a `[` (but not consuming the `[` char, i.e. not returning it as part of the match value) before...
- `\D` / `[^0-9]` - a non-digit. **NOTE**: to only negate ASCII digits, you may use `\D` with the `RegexOptions.ECMAScript` flag.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be:

```
\[\D[^]]*\]
# look for [
# \D - not a digit
# anything not ], zero or more times
# followed by ]
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/uU0zO7/1).

Answer (score 0):

Don't use so many parentheses.  Parentheses are both grouping *and* determining what's returned as the match.

```
\[([^0-9])
```

If you absolutely need to use the parentheses, use `(?:…)` for parentheses that group but are not returned as part of the match.

```
(?:(?:(?:\[)([^0-9])))
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe what you're searching for is `\[([^0-9])`
Do you expect `[123abc]` to pass?